# How to implement code like SomeObject.SomeFunction().SomeOtherFunction();

Tags: c#

Today, I searched a line of code which was written like:

```
SomeObject.SomeFunction().SomeOtherFunction();
```

I am unable to understand this. I tried to search it on Google about this but no luck.

Please help me to understand this.

Comment: That `SomeFunction()` returns an object which has a method `someOtherFunction()`.

Comment: `SomeObject.SomeFunction()` simply returns a value of a type that has a method `SomeOtherFunction`, there is nothing special to it. It's just as if you wrote e.g. `user.GetFullName().ToLower()`.

Comment: Try search using the words `method chaining`

Comment: SomeObject has a method SomeFunction which returns an object that itself exposes a SomeOtherFunction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following

```
public class FirstClass
{
    public SecondClass SomeFunction()
    {
        return new SecondClass();  
    }
}

public class SecondClass
{
    public void SomeOtherFunction()
    {

    }
}
```

So the following are equivalent.

```
 FirstClass SomeObject = new FirstClass();
 SomeObject.SomeFuntion().SomeOtherFunction();
```

OR

```
 FirstClass SomeObject = new FirstClass();
 SecondClass two = SomeObject.SomeFuntion();
 two.SomeOtherFunction();
```

Comment: No problem at all. The other answers are relevant as well with regards implementing Extensions or chaining methods for Fluent APIs but I think this is the most simplified OO example to demonstrate it

Answer (score 3):

SomeObject has a function called SomeFunction(). This function returns an object (of an unknown type for us, based on your example). This object has a function called SomeOtherFunction().

The question "how to implement" is a bit vague to answer, though.

Answer (score 2):

This is called **Fluent** coding or method chaining and is a method of programming that allows you to chain commands together. It is very common in LINQ where you might have something like this:

```
var result = myList.Where(x => x.ID > 5).GroupBy(x => x.Name).Sort().ToList();
```

This would give you all the records greater than 5, then grouped by name, sorted and returned as a list. The same code could be written in long hand like this:

```
var result = myList.Where(x => x.ID > 5);
result = result.GroupBy(x => x.Name);
result = result.Sort();
result = result.ToList();
```

But you can see this is much more long winded.

Answer (score 2):

This style of programming called [FluentInterface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) style.

Eg:

```
internal class FluentStyle
    {
        public FluentStyle ConnectToDb()
        {
            // some logic
            return this;
        }
        public FluentStyle FetchData()
        {
            // some logic
            return this;
        }
        public FluentStyle BindData()
        {
            // some logic
            return this;
        }
        public FluentStyle RefreshData()
        {
            // some logic
            return this;
        }
    }
```

And the object can be created and method can be consumed as below;

```
  var fluentStyle = new FluentStyle();
     fluentStyle.ConnectToDb().FetchData().BindData().RefreshData();
```

Comment: best answer, tells you what it is, and how to create it.

Answer (score 1):

This type of chaining may involve extension methods. These allow addition of new methods to existing classes (even those that you don't have the source code for).

e.g.

```
public static class StringExtender
{
    public static string MyMethod1(this string Input)
    {
        return ...
    }

    public static string MyMethod2(this string Input)
    {
        return ...
    }
}

....

public string AString = "some string";
public string NewString = AString.MyMethod1().MyMethod2();
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using extension methods

```
 public class FirstClass
{
}

public class SecondClass
{
}
public class ThridClass
{
}

public static class Extensions
{

    public static SecondClass GetSecondClass(this FirstClass f)
    {
        return new SecondClass();
    }
    public static ThridClass GetThridClass(this SecondClass s)
    {
        return new ThridClass();
    }
}
```

}

AND then you can ues

```
        FirstClass f= new FirstClass();
        f.GetSecondClass().GetThridClass();
```