# c# Nested Accessors?

Tags: c#, nested, accessor

I know how to do:

```
Class class = new Class();

class.Accessor
```

I don't know how to do:

```
class.Property.Accessor
class.Property.Subproperty.Accessor
class.Property.Subproperty.YetAnotherSubproperty.Accessor
```

Example analogy:

```
ListBox.Items.Count
```

An analogy to help explain (don't take it literally), I know how to create ListBox, I know how to create Count, but I don't know how to create Items

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything special here - just expose public properties in the relevant classes. Then you could chain the operations.

Comment: The word accessor is very misleading, in fact it should be "member".

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
class Animal
{
  // gets the heart of this animal
  public HeartType Heart
  {
    get
    {
      ...
    }
  }
}

class HeartType
{
  // gets the number of beats per minute
  public int Rate
  {
    get
    {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Then for `a` given by `var a = new Animal();` you could say

```
int exampleRate = a.Heart.Rate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question is quite cryptic, but i'll try.

Subproperties are just instances of other classes (or static classes) with their own properties.

Example:

```
class Class1
{
  public Class2Instance{get;set;} 

  public Class1()
  {
    Class2Instance =new Class2();     
  }
}

class Class2
{
  public string Greeting = "Hello";
}

//////
var c = new Class1();
Console.WriteLine(c.Class2Instance.Greeting);
```

Comment: public Class2Instance{get;set}  <--this won't compile

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question properly. But in your analogy, Items is a property/field of ListBox and the type of that property/field could be some collection. And that collection has the Count property.

Comment: this is better put as comment.

Answer (score 0):

I recently answered for similar question but it is more to do with a method chaining called [FluentInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854728/how-to-implement-code-like-someobject-somefunction-someotherfunction/16854881#16854881)  style.

In you case, it seems you are trying to call properties/public fields, which are part of  type; and these types are referenced in a nested fashion. With this in mind, the idea can be demonstrated as below;

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var one=new LevelOne();
           Console.WriteLine(one.LevelTwo.LevelThree.LastLevel);

        }
    }

    internal class LevelOne
    {
        public LevelOne()
        {
            LevelTwo = LevelTwo ?? new LevelTwo();
        }
        public LevelTwo LevelTwo { get; set; }
    }
    internal class LevelTwo
    {
        public LevelTwo()
        {
            LevelThree = LevelThree ?? new LevelThree();
        }
        public LevelThree LevelThree { get; set; }
    }
    internal class LevelThree
    {
        private string _lastLevel="SimpleString";
        public String LastLevel { get { return _lastLevel; } set { _lastLevel = value; } }
    }
```